# Start ruby script at boot as particular user

Tags: centos, service, users, ruby, god

wondering how I can have a ruby script started at boot, as a particular user.

This is on centos, so I imagine i need to create a service. ?

Comment: Is it going to be continuously running, or merely fired off and be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read `/usr/share/doc/initscripts-*/sysvinitfiles` for information on writing the initscript that you'll need for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to run this script at boot time, put it in that user's crontab with the special time `@reboot`.

If the script is a long-running process that would normally keep running until you reboot, then a adding a service is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Or u can add to /etc/rc.local somthing like this:

/usr/bin/sudo -u $user /path/to/script/script.rb

Comment: Or simply `su -c /path/to/script/script.rb $user`.